# Building case insensitive movie database

Tags: java, case-sensitive

I'm doing a university assignment, where I have to build 4 classes, one of which is a interface.

I need to make sure that strings are not case sensitive e.g. "the godfather", "The godfather", "The Godfather", are treated as the same movie.  how can I do this?

Comment: Override your Movie's equals class, and be sure that the name String check is case insensitive. Same for the hashCode method (perhaps convert it to all upper case before hashing it).

Comment: Strings are not by themselves case-sensitive or not. It's the **comparison** that is case sensitive or not. It's an important distinction because it teaches you that you need to think about when you are comparing. If it's about storing the Movie class in a HashMap, then read the comment above. If it's about sorting, you need to research case-insensitive sorting, etc. Once you can tell us exactly where in your code you are doing the comparison, people can help you with a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to what Aaron said, I would like to point out that it really depends on your implementation. By the way I am seeing it, you are tasked with creating a "search" function which searches through the database. Properly storing the movie names would be saving them in their actual format ("The Godfather") but when a search is initiated you want to match the search query with the database using the String .equalsIgnoreCase() function. For example:

```
String a = "The Godfather"
String b = "the godfather"
String c = "The Godfather"
String d = "thE GoDfaTher"
System.out.println(a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)); // Outputs true
System.out.println(a.equalsIgnoreCase(c)); // Outputs true
System.out.println(a.equalsIgnoreCase(d)); // Outputs true
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // Outputs false
```

Answer (score 0):

To make strings non case sensitive you should use the toLowerCase() method and make all the strings you manipulate in lowercase form. You can do this by doing:

```
stringA.toLowerCase();
```

Hope this helps, if this is not what you're looking for feel free to lemme know! :D